# JComboBox multiple items with same name

Tags: java, jcombobox, windowbuilder

Im working with Eclipse and WindowBuilder. In my JComboBox it is possible to show names multiple times. But the problem is that i can't select the second item with the same name. It always select the first one in the list. I can't work with the second one.
I can't post a picture, so here is the link to it: http://oi59.tinypic.com/15rmbcz.jpg

The code i use for example deleting a name in the list is the following:

```
for (Element customer : dList) {
    String name = customer.getChildText("name");
    if (GuiMain.item.equals(name)) {
        String birthday = customer.getChildText("birthday")
        if (bDay.equals(birthday)) {
            customer.getParent().removeContent(customer);
            document.setContent(root);

            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

            xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xmlOutput.output(document, new FileOutputStream("SAVE//File.xml"));
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted is not enough for me to figure out what is in your `JComboBox` and how you modify it. However, here is a piece of code that may help you:

```
private static class MyString {

    private static AtomicInteger objectCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private final String string;
    private final int id;

    public MyString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
        this.id = objectCount.getAndIncrement();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<MyString> vector = new Vector<>();
    vector.add(new MyString("One"));
    vector.add(new MyString("Two"));
    vector.add(new MyString("Two"));;
    vector.add(new MyString("Three"));

    JComboBox<MyString> box = new JComboBox<>(vector);
    box.addItemListener(e -> {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            MyString item = (MyString) e.getItem();
            System.out.println(String.format("Selected: %s (id=%s)", item, item.id));
        }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(box);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Note that `MyString` doesn't override `equals` method, which means that two objects are equal if they are the same instance (so the `id` is actually redundant, it is just printout).